# How to validate End date which is less than the Start date in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have two edit text box and I want to validate the end date which is less than the start date.

I have done simple validation, so how should I validate for example my Start Date is "2019-05-08" and my End Date is "2019-04-05" and if the end date less than it should give an error message saying "The end date is less than start date" how to do this.

Here is my code:

```
  ExpStDt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ExpStDt);
    textInputExpStDt = (TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.textInputExpStDt);
    ExpEndDt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ExpEndDt);
    textInputExpEndDt = (TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.textInputExpEndDt);


 if (validate()){
                // Get values from edit text fields.
 String Exp_St_Dt = ExpStDt.getText().toString();
               String Exp_End_Dt = ExpEndDt.getText().toString();

// Data inserted in the database
      .......
// This method is used to validate input given by user
  String Exp_St_Dt = ExpStDt.getText().toString();
            String Exp_End_Dt = ExpEndDt.getText().toString();
 // Handling validation for User Name field.
  if (Exp_St_Dt.isEmpty()) {
                valid = false;
                textInputExpStDt.setError("Please Enter The Expected Date Where you want to start Your leave");
                textInputExpStDt.requestFocus();
            } else {

                valid = true;
                textInputExpStDt.setError(null);
            }
            if (Exp_End_Dt.isEmpty()) {
                valid = false;
                textInputExpEndDt.setError("Please Enter the Expected Date Where you want to End Your leave");
                textInputExpEndDt.requestFocus();
            } else {
                valid = true;
                textInputExpEndDt.setError(null);
            }
 // Check validation for end date that is greater than start date
            SimpleDateFormat dfDate  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

                boolean b = false;
            try {
                if(dfDate.parse(Exp_St_Dt).before(dfDate.parse(Exp_End_Dt)))
                {
                    b = true;//If start date is before end date
                }
                else if(dfDate.parse(Exp_St_Dt).equals(dfDate.parse(Exp_End_Dt)))
                {
                    b = true;//If two dates are equal
                }
                else if (dfDate.parse(Exp_End_Dt).before(dfDate.parse(Exp_St_Dt)))
                {
                    b = false; //If start date is after the end date

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return valid;
        }
```

Please help me thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just convert two date to Date type, and use Date#getTime() method to compare

Comment: How to do it though?

Comment: `static SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");


public static boolean CheckDates(String d1, String d2) {

    retrun sdf.parse(d1) < sdf.parse(d2);

}`

Comment: I did this  public static boolean CheckDates("2012-07-12", "2012-06-12)" but its giving me some errors

Comment: sorry，i forgot getTime,`retrun sdf.parse(d1).getTime() < sdf.parse(d2).getTime();`

Comment: you can also try catch the convert,when error happen retrun false. it alway happen when the date string format wrong, i.e. '2012/07/12'

Comment: Yup still giving me errors 
  SimpleDateFormat dfDate  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                public static boolean CheckDates(String Exp_St_Dt, String Exp_End_Dt) { retrun sdf.parse(d1).getTime() < sdf.parse(d2).getTime() } <----- Giving me errors here

Comment: I'm still finding it difficult

Comment: Can you post a source code of it so that it is easy for me to understand

Comment: maybe you should check val name is correct,and you should type a ';' when a code end.it's a simple version below : `public static boolean checkDates(String start, String end) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        try {
            return sdf.parse(start).getTime() <= sdf.parse(end).getTime();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }`

Comment: SimpleDateFormat dfDate  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                public static boolean CheckDates(String Exp_St_Dt, String Exp_End_Dt )
                try {
                    if(dfDate.parse(Exp_St_Dt).before(dfDate.parse(Exp_End_Dt)))
                    {
                        valid = true;//If start date is before end date

Comment: it's okay. haha : )

Comment: But the problem is that when i write CheckDates(String Exp_St_Dt, String Exp_End_Dt ) the String gives me an error and also the closing brackets.

Comment: you just need coding conscientiously. And maybe you need review knowledge of java.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to compare 2 dates:

```
SimpleDateFormat dfDate  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
public static boolean CheckDates("2012-07-12", "2012-06-12)"    {
    boolean b = false;
    try {
        if(dfDate.parse(d1).before(dfDate.parse(d2)))
        {
            b = true;//If start date is before end date
        }
        else if(dfDate.parse(d1).equals(dfDate.parse(d2)))
        {
            b = true;//If two dates are equal
        }
        else
        {
            b = false; //If start date is after the end date
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: The return b; can I make it to return valid;

Comment: You can return whatever you want. In this case I'm returning true and false based on the conditions.

Comment: I tried this code  public static boolean CheckDates(String Exp_St_Dt, String Exp_End_Dt) but its still giving me errors in Strings